# Trying to install a fresh version of Ubuntu did not go well, now there is no OS installed at all

Tags: boot, mount, umount

this is gonna be painful to read because it's been a very long time since I did anything with my laptop other than just idle use, but here goes:

I was having some issues with my Asus Model No. F555U, and decided to open it up, clean the fan, and then try a fresh install of Ubuntu.  Done it before, everything was fine, figured if this would solve any little bugs I was having that would be it.

Instead, the installation didn't finish.  And it didn't give me any reason, or really "fail" officially, just that when I clicked "Continue" after picking my computer name and all that, it just started processing, and processing, and processing, for about 24 hours, so I rebooted and tried again.  Now without the disc, I just get the laptop booting up to "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported", and a list of possible commands.

Everything was backed up, but the more I've looked into this the more confused I get.  /dev/sda2 is mounted and locked, which seems to keep me from adjusting partitions, or from killing it at all when I try to just reformat everything entirely.

I know this is not hard info, but if anyone can point me in the right direction I'll get the right pictures and more helpful data, but a place to start would be a godsend at this point.

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean by " /dev/sda2 is mounted and locked"?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I can get the laptop to the "Try Ubuntu" stage, and when I try to install this way, it doesn't work.  So after some googling, I tried opening "Gparted", and it said that /dev/sda2 was mounted, and it had the little key symbol next to it, so I couldn't do anything to change that partition.  I don't know why that's important, but I've been browsing like 30 different tabs and it's hard to figure out what information I should relay.

Comment: You can't manipulate a partition while is mounted. In GParted, right click on the partition and you will find the "unmount" option.

Comment: You haven't said what release of Ubuntu you tried to install, nor if you validated your ISO & subsequent write to installation media (critical given you mention the installation didn't finish, nor if you switched to a terminal & looked at issues the installer was having etc.. without release details I can only speak broadly).

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Well that WAS the issue, in the time since I posted I changed the partition, but got to the end of installation, and am met with "Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed.  This is a fatal error." And then... that's it.  It'll prompt me to reboot, eject the DVD on which I've got Ubuntu, and then load into the blank screen that says:


[ 1870.733065] sd-umoun [28783]: Failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy
Then a similar repetitive notice about oldroot/dev, oldroot/cdrom, it can't detach loopback, then says reboot and doesn't actually restart.

Comment: @guiverc 20.04.1, and past that I have no idea what you're describing, but if you don't mind explaining I can find out!

Comment: If you try to start the installer with a "dirty" system, that's no way to do a "clean" installation. Format/erase the whole disk first

Comment: @nmath I've selected "format everything directly to hell" in the installation process, and it does not format everything directly to hell.  Is there a step I'm missing in this exorcism?

Comment: There's no such option... Use the "Disks" app in the live session to format your disk. When it's successful then reboot and start the installation

Comment: @nmath I don't even seem to be able to get back to trying Ubuntu from the disc at this point, so I guess I'll get back to you.  It's just stuck at "PCIe Bus Error" over and over.

Comment: Then my guess is that your installation media is invalid. Did you verify both the integrity of the download and the flash?  If you're not sure you did everything right, I suggest downloading the bittorrent link under "alternative downloads" and using balena etcher to flash the ISO to USB.  These methods automatically verify integrity

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 though subsequent steps are automatic on 20.04 media (ie. it'll automatically validate the ISO assuming it's checksums are valid; the ISO step confirms that, and you don't skip the step).  Issues with media usually show as *squashfs* errors easily scanned for with `dmesg` in terminal